# Coldfusion: CFHTTP landing page redirection

Tags: redirect, coldfusion, cfhttp

I am working on a project that requires a CFHTTP call to book publishers that returns an excerpt from their site. My issue is that one of the publisher's URLS is converted to another and I can't seem to figure out how to get the returned information from them.

For example: The url I would visit is http://www.pubsite.com/bookID/99999 
When I go to that site in the browser, it automatically redirects me to: http://www.pubsite.com/publisherID/12345

This is fine and I can see the information I need. However, when I try to automate this process using Coldfusion, I am stuck. There is no way to know what that publisherID is ahead of time.

My code is this:

```
<cfset thisURL = "http://www.pubsite.com/bookID/#Trim(arguments.BID)#">
<cfhttp method="get" url="#thisURL#" useragent="#CGI.http_user_agent#"  result="objGet" redirect="true" resolveurl="true"/>
<cfdump var="#objGet#" />
```

Nothing in the returned dump (header or filecontent) indicates the publisherID, or the true landing URL, and I get a ResponseCode of 200 so I don't know what to do next.

After much Google searching, I'm stumped. Thanks for any insight!

EDIT TO INCLUDE DUMP:

```
struct
 Charset    UTF-8
 ErrorDetail    [empty string]
 Filecontent    
 binary
 6033687967848980
 [truncated]
 Header HTTP/1.1 200 OK X-Firenze-Processing-Time: 422.785 X-Firenze-Processing-Time: 626.552 X-Varnish-Cache: miss X-SmartBan-URL: /content/1177/0959683607085571 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: detect-robot: 0.315 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: add-external-dependencies-info: 0.033 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: content-pre-retrieve: 307.973 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: add-req-info: 10.427 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: authn-authz: 48.986 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: ac-info-request: 4.702 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: login-check: 2.104 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: last-authorized-identity: 1.769 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: retrieve-current-issue: 0.038 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: retrieve-content-page-content: 8.148 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: retrieve-content-page-prev: 3.260 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: retrieve-content-page-next: 3.310 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: retrieve-ads: 9.608 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: retrieve-session-data: 4.577 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: log-builder: 3.302 X-Firenze-Processing-Times: servlet: 207.151 Accept-Ranges: bytes X-XXXX-RequestId: VPTH5atDd2QAABNxM48AAAD- Vary: Accept-Encoding Connection: close X-XXXX-SessionId: m3H5rW2RVOiJ7qb3WTMt0w Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=FF1AA7D6946D968D5E100C8FD1B8205C.wa126.XXXX.org; Path=/ Age: 0 Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 Server: nginx/0.7.67 X-Varnish: 2761793264 X-Varnish-Hostname: varnish8.XXXX.org X-SmartBan-Host: hol.XXXX.com x-XXXX-user: memno=1000480925; name=XXXX; type=INST; ip_access=true; password_access=true Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2015 20:28:21 GMT Via: 1.1 varnish
 Mimetype   text/html
 Responseheader 
  struct
   Accept-Ranges    bytes
   Age  0
   Connection   close
   Content-Type text/html;charset=UTF-8
   Date Mon, 02 Mar 2015 20:28:21 GMT
   Explanation  OK
   Http_Version HTTP/1.1
   Server   nginx/0.7.67
   Set-Cookie   JSESSIONID=FF1AA7D6946D968D5E100C8FD1B8205C.wa126.XXXX.org;        Path=/
  Status_Code   200
  Vary  Accept-Encoding
  Via   1.1 varnish
  X-Firenze-Processing-Time 
   struct
    1   422.785
    2   626.552
  X-Firenze-Processing-Times    
   struct
    1   detect-robot: 0.315
    10  retrieve-content-page-content: 8.148
    11  retrieve-content-page-prev: 3.260 
    12  retrieve-content-page-next: 3.310
    13  retrieve-ads: 9.608
    14  retrieve-session-data: 4.577
    15  log-builder: 3.302
    16  servlet: 207.151
    2   add-external-dependencies-info: 0.033
    3   content-pre-retrieve: 307.973
    4   add-req-info: 10.427
    5   authn-authz: 48.986
    6   ac-info-request: 4.702
    7   login-check: 2.104
    8   last-authorized-identity: 1.769
    9   retrieve-current-issue: 0.038
  X-XXXX-RequestId  VPTH5atDd2QAABNxM48AAAD-
  X-XXXX-SessionId  m3H5rW2RVOiJ7qb3WTMt0w
  X-SmartBan-Host   hol.XXXX.com
  X-SmartBan-URL    /content/1177/0959683607085571
  X-Varnish 2761793264
  X-Varnish-Cache   miss
  X-Varnish-Hostname    varnish8.XXXX.org
  x-XXXX-user   memno=1000480925; name=XXXX; type=INST; ip_access=true; password_access=true
  Statuscode    200 OK
  Text  YES
```

Comment: How many redirects are happening? The `cfhttp` tag will only follow a maximum of four redirects. If there are more than that it will function as if the `redirect` attribute were `false`. The `cfhttp.responseHeader.Location` variable contains the redirection path. It may only be available if you have `redirect=false`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried setting it to false and re-running, however I do not get any responseHeader.Location results. (Also, and forgive my ignorance, but how do I know how many redirects there were?)

Comment: Can you share the dump output you are seeing? To see the traffic flow open up your browser's dev tools and watch the network section as you browse to the initial URL.

Comment: Please post the dump in your question by [edit]ing it. Then you don't need to truncate it and it will format better.

Comment: Watching the network tools, it looks like there is one redirect. The initial URL shows a 302 (Moved Temporarily) result. The next line is the proper landing URL.

Comment: So the dump indicates that the filecontent is binary? What version of ColdFusion are you running? Possibly related [to this issue](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/01/weird-behaviour-with-cfhttp-and-json.html) which might be remedied [by this work around](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2496-using-cfhttp-getasbinary-to-normalize-http-response-file-content-format.htm).  What type of response are you expecting? The mime-type reports text/html and the text is yes.